# Why EF Core is filtering wrong on subsequent query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-5

I can't find a proper title for the question, advices are welcome...

I'm on EF Core in a net5.0 project.
The tables are 4: Account, AccountDevice, Device, Gateway.
The database schema is: `[Account] --(1,n)--> [AccountDevice] --(1,n)--> [Device] --(1,1)--> [Gateway]`

In the `Device` table there is a navigation column `GatewayMacAddress`.

This query works fine:

```
 var account = await context.Account.Where(a => a.Id == 1)
                .Include(a => a.AccountDevices.Where(ad => ad.Device.GatewayMacAddress == "112233445566"))
                .ThenInclude(ad => ad.Device)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.Gateway)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The query above filters out all devices with gateway mac address "112233445566". It uses the EF Core 5 [where-in-include](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/21b9a35db594f7a383e855f922babbe54b3d38c5) feature.

If I do the 'old school' query, for old school I mean without the *where-in-include* feature:

```
var ac = await context.Account.Where(a => a.Id == 1)
                .Include(a => a.AccountDevices)
                .ThenInclude(ad => ad.Device)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.Gateway)
                .Select(a => new
                {
                    Account = a,
                    AccountDevices = a.AccountDevices.Where(ad => ad.Device.GatewayMacAddress == "112233445566")
                })
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

it also works, filtering out Device with mac address "112233445566".

The proble arises if I do the 2 queries sequentially in this order, on the same context:

1. old school query
2. new school query

In this case the second query (the new school) return all devices, it's not filtering the mac address "112233445566".
I can't understand if it's a bug or else...

Comment: You may not be wait long enough to get the MAC.  Try switching the order of the queries and see what happens.

Comment: `.Include(a => a.AccountDevices)` - the context now contains all devices for this account, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Switching the queries order make it works. Executing the queries separately make it works. Executing in that order make the second query goes wrong